# How can I use C sharp codebehind to disable/hide a .Net LinkButton within my ListView based on it's binded value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, binding

Below is my ProductBacklog.aspx page with my listview alternating item template (same code as item template). What I want to be able to do is on page load to in the codebehind file get the binded Priority value for each item and where the value of Priority is 1 to disable the button UpButton and where the value pf Priority is MAX to disable the button DownButton.

```
<asp:ListView ID="POListView" Visible="False" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BacklogItemId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <AlternatingItemTemplate>
      <span style="">Priority 
         <asp:Label ID="PriorityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priority") + ": " %>' />
         <asp:Label ID="StoryDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StoryDescription") %>' />
         <br />
         Project ID:
         <asp:Label ID="ProjectIdlabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectId") %>' />
         <br />
         Project Title:
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>' />
         <br />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="DownButton" Text="<i class='fa fa-fw fa-arrow-down'></i>" runat="server" OnClick="DownButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Priority") + ";" + Eval("ProjectId") + ";" + Eval("BacklogItemId")%>' />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="UpButton" OnClick="UpButton_OnClickButton_Click" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Priority") + ";" + Eval("ProjectId") + ";" + Eval("BacklogItemId") %>' Text="<i class='fa fa-fw fa-arrow-up'></i>" />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" OnClientClick="return confirmation();" OnClick="DeleteButton_OnClick_OnClickButton_Click" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Priority") + ";" + Eval("ProjectId") + ";" + Eval("BacklogItemId")%>' Text="<i class='fa fa-fw fa-trash'></i>" />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text=" <i class='fa fa-fw fa-edit'></i>" />
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you added any code-behind yet?  What have you tried that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a binding expression on the enabled property

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpButton" OnClick="UpButton_OnClickButton_Click" 
  runat="server" 
  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Priority") + ";" + Eval("ProjectId") + ";" + 
    Eval("BacklogItemId") %>' Text="<i class='fa fa-fw fa-arrow-up'></i>" 
  Enabled='<%# CType(Eval("Priority"), Int) != MAX_PRIORITY %>' 
/>
```